# Kerberos Authentication in OSI PI in Java

Tags: java, rest, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos, osisoft

I am newbie in terms of `Kerberos` Authentication.

I am able to login into access the API urls directly from browser by providing username and password.I check in Event Viewer by enabling `debug` logs and it gave me following output:

```
[PIWebAPI] {fd479633-2395-43f7-8fd0-8a028257d664}: Request executing as XXX\utkarsh.saraf.
GET /piwebapi
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml; q=0.9, image/webp, image/apng, */*; q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US, en; q=0.9
Authorization: Negotiate [Redacted]
Host: XX.XX.XX.XX
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
```

I am trying to achieve programatically in Java by following these articles but slight confused about conf files such `krb5.conf` and `login.conf` files mentioned in these:

1) http://www.chrisweldon.net/sharepoint/sharepoint-rest-api-authentication-from-java/

2) https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html

Are these files needed to be created by me or will be present on server?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the OSI PI Web API? Are you an administrator of the PI System? Do you know what authentication methods are allowed for your OSI PI Web API (Kerberos, Basic, Bearer) (You can have multiple authentication methods)?